# How do I return a list of all data entries matching bit flags efficently?

Tags: python, search, bit-manipulation

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to search through some data and get a list of entries which match some bit flags.

## In Abstract Terms

The data looks like this:

- 1 byte group code
- 4 bytes (32 bits) of flags
- a descriptive name string for the flag
- a unique ID integer for the flag

So essentially there are 32 entries per group and up to 128 groups (the first bit of group code is always 0) for a total of 4096 possible entries (though the number is more likely going to be around 150 entries total spread across 5 groups).

Right now I have this data in an SQLite database, but that's neither here nor there, I am happy to put it in a list of dicts or other formats, whatever will be efficient for searching.

What I need to do is to take an incoming hex string which contains a group code followed by 32 bits of flags and return all the matching flag names and IDs for the flags which are turned on.

## Specific Example

I am working with MIDI SysEx data. I need to take a MIDI SysEx command coming from an instrument and match it to a database/list of dicts which contain descriptive names for a series of flags in the data and create a new list of those flags which are turned on in the SysEx command.

### Example Data

Note, this data is currently actually stored in a SQLite table and not in a list of dicts like this, but it could be, I'm open to efficient ways of storing it.

```
instruments = [{'id': 1, 'group': 0x00, 'flag': 0x00200000, 'name': 'Bass'},
               {'id': 2, 'group': 0x00, 'flag': 0x00000800, 'name': 'Trumpet'},
               {'id': 3, 'group': 0x10, 'flag': 0x00004000, 'name': 'Violin'},
               {'id': 4, 'group': 0x18, 'flag': 0x00010000, 'name': 'Chimes'},
               {'id': 5, 'group': 0x18, 'flag': 0x00000200, 'name': 'Flute'},
               {'id': 6, 'group': 0x18, 'flag': 0x00000800, 'name': 'Wooden Flute'},
               {'id': 7, 'group': 0x10, 'flag': 0x00000200, 'name': 'Horn'}]
```

### Example Incoming Data to Select On

The incoming MIDI data might look like:

```
midiData1 = 0x1000400200
midiData2 = 0x1800000A0
```

In other words midiData1 is an OR of the flags 0x00004000 and 0x00000200 from group 0x10 and midiData2 is an OR of the flags 0x00000200 and 0x00000800 from group 0x18.

### Expected Output

The goal would be to return results like:

```
result1 = [{'id': 3, 'group': 0x10, 'flag': 0x00004000, 'name': 'Violin'},{'id': 7, 'group': 0x10, 'flag': 0x00000200, 'name': 'Horn'}]
result2 = [{'id': 5, 'group': 0x18, 'flag': 0x00000200, 'name': 'Flute'}, {'id': 6, 'group': 0x18, 'flag': 0x00000800, 'name': 'Wooden Flute'}]
```

Essentially unORing the data and returning the data associated with each flag that was turned on.

## Conclusion

As I mentioned I am open to both how to store and how to search this data because I recognize there may be a particular storage method which allows for efficient searching operations. For example, perhaps some database has a built-in method for selecting rows which match a bit mask. On the other hand the time to call an external database may mean some internal searching method in Python is faster even if more complex. I'm open to all solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: In the example data, the flag values only ever have 1 bit set. Does this apply to all your data? Do you actually need to store the flag as a bitfield, or could you just store the index of the set bit, e.g. instead of 0x00000800 store 10?

Comment: Good question. In the instruments data it's just one bit per instrument so you could just store the index of the set bit (1-32). The only time you will have multiple bits set is when you are receiving (or sending) data indicating multiple instruments are turned on. See for example "Example Incoming Data to Select On" and "Expected Output"